# Firebase push notifications using NestJS

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, nestjs

I've been trying to use the push notification service from FCM inside my NestJS server. But I haven't found any clear documentation on this for nestjs, I'm new to this and I was hoping if you could help me by describing the exact process or sharing relatable URLs that you think they might be helpful. I do have a built nestjs server app and a firebase app, and my local server is connected to the firebase app. I just dont know how to use the FCM service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fcm service support to use with restful api, for old version of fcm api, nestjs server can send http request to firebase with server key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use messaging sdk as well.

First go to Firebase console, open the project you  willing to use with messaging, under "Project settings", click on "Service accounts" tab and "Generate new private key", download the key and add it to your nestjs project.

On your nestjs project, add firebase-admin:

```
npm i firebase-admin
```

Create a file such as messaging.provider.ts with bellow code, replace PATH_TO_YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE to downloaded private key (i.e. ./src/config...':

```
import { Provider } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as fs from 'fs';

export const MessagingProvider = 'lib:messaging';

export const messagingProvider: Provider = {
  provide: MessagingProvider,
  useFactory: async () => {
    const jsonString = fs.readFileSync(
      '$PATH_TO_YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE',
      'utf-8',
    );
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    await admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert({
        projectId: jsonData.project_id,
        clientEmail: jsonData.client_email,
        privateKey: jsonData.private_key,
      }),
    });
    return admin.messaging(admin.app());
  },
};
```

Create a module importing this provider:

```
@Module({
  providers: [messagingProvider, MessagingService],
  exports: [MessagingService],
})
export class MessagingModule {}
```

Inject it anywhere to use this messaging instance, in my case I created a service to use it:

```
    @Injectable()
export class MessagingService implements IMessaging {
  constructor(
    @Inject(MessagingProvider)
    private readonly messaging: admin.messaging.Messaging,
  ) {}
  private android: AndroidConfig = {
    priority: 'high',
  };

  private apns = {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        contentAvailable: true,
      },
    },
    headers: {
      'apns-priority': '5', // Must be `5` when `contentAvailable` is set to true.
    },
  };

  async sendMessageToTokens(
    params: IMessaginToTokensParams,
  ): Promise<string[]> {
    const { title, body, payload, tokens } = params;
    return await this.messaging
      .sendEachForMulticast({
        tokens: tokens,
        data: payload,
        notification: {
          title: title,
          body: body,
        },
        android: this.android,
        apns: this.apns,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.failureCount > 0) {
          const failedTokens: string[] = [];
          response.responses.forEach((resp, idx) => {
            if (!resp.success) {
              failedTokens.push(tokens[idx]);
            }
          });
          return failedTokens;
        } else {
          return [];
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw new HttpException(
          `Error sending message: ${err.message}`,
          HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT,
        );
      });
  }

  async sendMessageToTopic(params: IMessaginToTopicParams): Promise<string> {
    const { title, body, payload, topic } = params;
    return await this.messaging
      .send({
        topic: topic,
        data: payload,
        notification: {
          title: title,
          body: body,
        },
        android: this.android,
        apns: this.apns,
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw new HttpException(
          `Error sending message: ${err.message}`,
          HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT,
        );
      });
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param title
   * @param body
   * @param condition You can include up to five topics in your conditional expression. I.E. "'TopicA' in topics && ('TopicB' in topics || 'TopicC' in topics)"
   * @returns
   */
  async sendMessageToCondition(
    params: IMessaginToConditionParams,
  ): Promise<string> {
    const { title, body, payload, condition } = params;
    // sample condition: "'TopicA' in topics && ('TopicB' in topics || 'TopicC' in topics)"
    return await this.messaging
      .send({
        condition: condition,
        data: payload,
        notification: {
          title: title,
          body: body,
        },
        android: this.android,
        apns: this.apns,
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw new HttpException(
          `Error sending message: ${err.message}`,
          HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT,
        );
      });
  }
}
```

You could use this service anywhere, importing the MessagingModule